# How create custom feedback button?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

How create custom button with expression blend 4?
I insert an image into the button and receive feedback

thank

Comment: This question needs more detail. You'll be lucky if you get the following answer: 1. Open expression blend 4. 2. Create a button. 3. Success

Comment: What do you mean by "receive feedback"?

Answer (score 1):

My guess: you would like to create a button with an image inside, which the click event triggers [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to send an email with the feedback.

There are dozens of tutorial how to make a button in Blend. It's prety simple

1. Drag the button on the screen.
2. Change Content of the button to the image or create new/edit dupicate style/templeate of the button. Change TextBlock to Image.

That's the UI now you need the logic. Which is a job for Visual Studio.

(You can always create all UI in Visual Studio - I prefer this way)

Example of XAML

```
<Button>
      <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="img.png" />  
      </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Then you in code behind the page create a EmailComposeTask.

```
        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailComposeTask.To = "foo@bar.com";
        emailComposeTask.Subject = "Windows Phone 7 app - Feedback";
        emailComposeTask.Show();
```